# Reciprocal lattice points connection to multiple slit experiment

Tags: diffraction, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Why does the X-ray diffraction of 1 lattice plane result only in a single reciprocal lattice point (Is this somehow related to the fact that the lattice plane is a 2D diffraction grating)? Does this reciprocal lattice point correspond to the zero order maximum of the diffraction pattern ? (Maybe the other maxima are of such low intensity that they are not visible diffraction spots ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you perform Fourier transform on a 2D translationally periodic lattice you will know that the result is translational periodicity in 2D with the third dimension unbounded in reciprocal space, i.e., an array of parallel lines as opposed to a single point.

I don't quite understand your second question.